# Find Duplicate Documents in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a solution to find duplicate(exact) Docs in ElasticSearch.
I've read https://qbox.io/blog/minimizing-document-duplication-in-elasticsearch and tried it but its results are not as I expected  as example this is my sample simple query :

```
GET /last_month_ads/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "fields": [
     "title"
  ], 
  "aggs": {
    "duplicateCount": {
      "terms": {
      "field": "title",
      "size" : 3        
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duplicateDocuments": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the result is

```
{
   "took": 981,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 482909,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "duplicateCount": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 11667,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 1958146,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "CM",
               "doc_count": 46867,
               "duplicateDocuments": {
                  "hits": {
                     "total": 46867,
                     "max_score": 1,
                     "hits": [
                        {
                           "_index": "last_month_ads",
                           "_type": "ads",
                           "_id": "AV73EtoBQTqkjEa7YQG1",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "id": "20642316",
                              "cat_id": "43606",
                              "user_id": "1825875",
                              "title": "125 CM HOME",
                              "desc": "DESC"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "_index": "last_month_ads",
                           "_type": "ads",
                           "_id": "AV73EtpdQTqkjEa7YQHc",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "id": "20642379",
                              "cat_id": "43604",
                              "user_id": "4642299",
                              "title": "Home with Big CM",
                              "desc": "DESC"
                           }
                        },
                        {
                           "_index": "last_month_ads",
                           "_type": "ads",
                           "_id": "AV73Etp6QTqkjEa7YQHp",
                           "_score": 1,
                           "_source": {
                              "id": "20642409",
                              "cat_id": "43607",
                              "user_id": "4813303",
                              "title": "100 of live CM is here ",
                              "desc": "DESC"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },

            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**I'm looking for Exact (or similar) titles not  abundance words in titles, how can I get get Duplicate(similar) Docs in Elastic Search?**

Comment: Please provide your index settings and analyzers for title field, it looks like your field is tokenized and analyzed

Comment: @Ivan thanks for your attention,  this is just test, still I haven't made origin index, if it needs I can change it as what is the best for it, find the solution is the more important.